# C# MVC Import from Excel / dataadapter.fil(ds)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

Here is the controller code:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            if (Request.Files["file"].ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Request.Files["file"].FileName);

                if (fileExtension == ".xls" || fileExtension == ".xlsx")
                {
                    string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads") + Request.Files["file"].FileName;
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileLocation))
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(fileLocation);
                    }
                    Request.Files["file"].SaveAs(fileLocation);
                    string excelConnectionString = string.Empty;
                    excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                    //connection String for xls file format.
                    if (fileExtension == ".xls")
                    {
                        excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                    }
                    //connection String for xlsx file format.
                    else if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
                    {
                        excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                    }
                    //Create Connection to Excel work book and add oledb namespace
                    OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
                    excelConnection.Open();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                    dt = excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                    if (dt == null)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }

                    String[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
                    int t = 0;
                    //excel data saves in temp file here.
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        excelSheets[t] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                        t++;
                    }
                    OleDbConnection excelConnection1 = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);

                    string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", excelSheets[0]);
                    ////////////////////////////////////////////TEST///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    //string query = string.Format("SELECT * INTO [FSM].[temp_DFS_Akustik] FROM [{0}]", excelSheets[0]);
                    ////////////////////////////////////////////TEST///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, excelConnection1))
                    {
                        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
                        ////////////////////////////////////////////TEST///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                        ////////////////////////////////////////////TEST///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    }
                }
                if (fileExtension.ToString().ToLower().Equals(".xml"))
                {
                    string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads") + Request.Files["FileUpload"].FileName;
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileLocation))
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(fileLocation);
                    }

                    Request.Files["FileUpload"].SaveAs(fileLocation);
                    XmlTextReader xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(fileLocation);
                    // DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    ds.ReadXml(xmlreader);
                    xmlreader.Close();
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString;
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);

                    string query = "INSERT INTO [fanselect_man].[FSM].[DFS_Akustik](MessID,KL_ID,MP_ID,LwLin50ss,LwLin63ss,LwLin80ss,LwLin100ss,LwLin125ss,LwLin160ss,LwLin200ss,LwLin250ss,LwLin315ss,LwLin400ss,LwLin500ss,LwLin630ss,LwLin800ss,LwLin1000ss,LwLin1250ss,LwLin1600ss,LwLin2000ss,LwLin2500ss,LwLin3150ss,LwLin4000ss,LwLin5000ss,LwLin6300ss,LwLin8000ss,LwLin10000ss,LwLin12500ss,LwLin16000ss,LwLin20000ss,LwLin50ds,LwLin63ds,LwLin80ds,LwLin100ds,LwLin125ds,LwLin160ds,LwLin200ds,LwLin250ds,LwLin315ds,LwLin400ds,LwLin500ds,LwLin630ds,LwLin800ds,LwLin1000ds,LwLin1250ds,LwLin1600ds,LwLin2000ds,LwLin2500ds,LwLin3150ds,LwLin4000ds,LwLin5000ds,LwLin6300ds,LwLin8000ds,LwLin10000ds,LwLin12500ds,LwLin16000ds,LwLin20000ds) VALUES ('" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][3].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][4].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][5].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][6].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][7].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][8].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][9].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][10].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][11].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][12].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][13].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][14].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][15].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][16].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][17].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][18].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][19].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][20].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][21].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][22].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][23].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][24].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][25].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][26].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][27].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][28].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][29].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][30].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][31].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][32].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][33].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][34].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][35].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][36].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][37].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][38].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][39].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][40].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][41].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][42].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][43].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][44].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][45].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][46].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][47].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][48].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][49].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][50].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][51].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][52].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][53].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][54].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][55].ToString() + "', '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][56].ToString() + "')";
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            ViewBag.view_dfs_akustik = dbman.View_DFS_Akustik.ToList();
            return View();
        }
```

You can see, that i have write all values and columns after the insert into call. Now it's my question... Is there a way to create a #table and then i call the insert like "Insert Into [...] FROM [#table]"?? What can i do with the dataadapter?

Thanks.
Greetz
Vegeta_77

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and another time i got the solution by my self:

string strConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString;

```
        //file upload path
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);

        //Create connection string to Excel work book
        string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False";
        //Create Connection to Excel work book
        OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
        //Create OleDbCommand to fetch data from Excel
        excelConnection.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt = excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        if (dt == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        String[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
        int t = 0;
        //excel data saves in temp file here.
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            excelSheets[t] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            t++;
        }

        OleDbConnection excelConnection1 = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);

        string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", excelSheets[0]);

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, excelConnection);
        //excelConnection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader dReader;
        dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection);
        //Give your Destination table name
        sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "[FSM].[DFS_Akustik]";
        sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
        excelConnection.Close();

        ViewBag.view_dfs_akustik = dbman.View_DFS_Akustik.ToList();
        return View();
```

Greetz 
Vegeta_77